# address operator in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am porting cpp code to Objective C.

In **cpp**

```
void create(INT32u &uLen)
{
 sprintf((char*)ps[uLen],"%x%d",val,val1);
}
```

In **Objective C**

```
-(void)create:(uint32_t**)uLen
{
 sprintf((char*)ps[uLen],"%x%d",val,val1);
}
```

This gives me an error as the index will take only integer value. How do i need to pass the variable. The original variable passed should also change with the changes made with the variable uLen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Objective-C is a strict superset of C you still can do this: pass a pointer to your integer and use the dereference operator (prefix *) to look up the value that exists at that address:

```
-(void)create:(uint32_t*)uLen
{
    sprintf((char*)ps[(*uLen)],"%x%d",val,val1);
}
```

However, pass by reference [is not very common in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331791/arguments-by-reference-in-objective-c/3332062#3332062). Actually, it is largely limited to `NSError**`. Why not pass a simple integer and return the new value since you are currently returning `void`?

```
-(uint32_t)create:(uint32_t)uLen
{
    sprintf((char*)ps[uLen],"%x%d",val,val1);
    ...
    return newValue;
}
```

Comment: This will not change my original value passed.I need to change the original value passed with the changes made to the uLen value.If i'm passing a=10 to uLen.And uLen=a+5; then a should get changed to 15.If i use (**uLen) then i cant use it to assign the index of an array.

Comment: @ron: This will change your original value passed. You need to use the dereference operator: *uLen = a+5;

Comment: Thanks a lot.I could not guess this simple funda.Thanks for helping me understand.