# passing out parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, out-parameters

I wrote a method with an out parameter:

```
-(NSString *)messageDecryption:(NSString *)receivedMessage outParam:(out)messageCondent
{   
    messageCondent = [receivedMessage substringFromIndex:2];
    return [receivedMessage substringToIndex:1];
}
```

Then I passed the param like this:

```
NSString *messageCondent;
NSString *mode = [myclassobject messageDecryption:message outParam:messageCondent];
```

However, there is a problem.  The out parameter value is not being set properly.  Can any one help me to do this correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't you specify a type? outParam:(out NSString *)?

Comment: I've never actually seen this `out` method used before. I think most people simply implement value by reference. (Check the correct answer on this page: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1502936?threadID=1502936)

Comment: Take into consideration that [pass by reference in Cocoa/iOS is largely limited to `NSError**`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331791/arguments-by-reference-in-objective-c/3332062#3332062). If you need to return more than one value at a time, that begs for a structure or, more often, a class.

Comment: `out` is a keyword in Objective-C that was related to Distributed Objects. It isn't used much anymore.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create the method to accept a pointer to the object.

```
-(NSString *)messageDecryption:(NSString *)receivedMessage outParam:(NSString**)messageCondent
{   
    *messageCondent = [receivedMessage substringFromIndex:2];
    return [receivedMessage substringToIndex:1];

}
```

Pass in the reference to the local object.

```
NSString *messageCondent = nil;
NSString *mode = [myclassobject messageDecryption:message outParam:&messageCondent];
```

Comment: and for giving an explicit type to the parameter.

Comment: Note that use of out parameters in Objective-C is exceedingly rare; pretty much limited only `NSError**`...

Comment: is there any major problm with out param?

Answer (score 11):

An "out parameter" is by definition a pointer to a pointer.

Your method should look like this:

```
-(NSString *)messageDecryption:(NSString *)receivedMessage outParam:(NSString **)messageCondent
{   
    *messageCondent = [receivedMessage substringFromIndex:2];
    return [receivedMessage substringToIndex:1];
}
```

This dereferences the passed-in pointer to get at the actual object reference and then assigns that to whatever `[receivedMessage substringFromIndex:2]` returns.

Invoking this method is quite simple:

```
NSString *messageCondent = nil;
NSString *mode = [myclassobject messageDecryption:message outParam:&messageCondent];
```

Comment: No, an "out parameter" is a pointer to a *value*. That the value is a pointer is only true if the value is an object. But it could just as well be an `int`