# Assigning nil to a member variable which is passed to a method

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables, local-variables

I'd like to assign `nil` to an object, which is an ivar, passed in as a parameter to a method, something like this.

```
- (int)trashObjectPassedIn:(Banana* banana) {
    banana = nil;

    return 42;
}
```

Of course, if I call it like this: `[self trashObjectPassedIn:oldBanana];` oldBanana is untouched - only the local parameter is assigned.

Is there any way I can assign `nil` to the original object?

Comment: No there's not a way to do this. Ok there may be a hacky way, but if there is please don't use it as it'll cause all kinds of issues, especially if you're using ARC.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't just set it to `nil` in the calling context?

Comment: Can you explain why you'd want to do this? Maybe we can help provide alternative solutions?

Comment: @JoshCaswell The reason I'm doing this is because I have a number of objects - a cost, a sell and a margin. I can set any two of them and evaluate to give me the remaining unset value. If two are set (for example, cost and sell) and I then choose to set the third object (margin), I wish for cost and sell to be cleared - more specifically, assigned nil.

I was doing this with member variables, as I only needed it done in one place, but now I have a situation where I need to apply this to a different cost, sell and margin which aren't member variables of the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest finding an alternative approach. Your trashObjectPassedIn is passed a *reference* to the banana. You can nil that, but nothing will happen to the actual banana.

If you want the banana to be deleted (and you're using ARC) then you should nil the property or member variable that *owns* the banana.

Answer (score 2):

Although this seems strange, there are some (though not many) legitimate reasons to do this and you can do this by passing a pointer to your objects pointer. This is called pass by reference, where objective c typically is pass by value. You can see this being used in Cocoa in any method which accepts an NSError, e.g. `save:` in `NSManagedObjectContext`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331791/arguments-by-reference-in-objective-c) has a more detailed description

change the method declaration to be

```
- (int)trashObjectPassedIn:(Banana **)banana
```

and pass the value by calling

```
int result = [self trashObjectPassedIn:&banana];
```

and then inside the method you can set the value:

```
*banana = nil;
```

Comment: In this particular case this will leak the object pointed to by `banana`.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't sure about that. I think its pretty unlikely this is what the answer to the question _should_ be anyway, it seems much simpler to just nil the value in the calling context

Comment: Yeah, it leaks under ARC and in MRR you'll have to autorelease it first (probably on the calling end). But I agree with you, if you're close enough to an object to do this, do it right, i.e. through the property.

Comment: I get this error with this solution `Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back`. If I use the `__strong` version that @carlVeazey suggests, I don't get this error.

Comment: I tried this way with a local variable without warning but if you are using a property I would go with @CarlVeazey's answer, since it handles this, and memory management

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using ARC, and your instance variable is a `strong` reference, do it like this:

```
- (int)trashObjectPassedIn:(Banana *__strong *)banana) 
{
    *banana = nil;
    return 42;
}
```

That keeps the object from leaking. Note that this won't work with `weak` references. If you're not using ARC I think this will be a lot tougher to make it work generally and safely.

**Edit**: forgot to show how to call it: `[self trashObjectPassedIn:&_myBanana]` where `_myBanana` is your instance variable.