# Obj-C: Alternatives to pass by reference

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns

So, I got a 2 variables declared in a class, let´s call it `model.h` and in this class i initialize instances of the classes `Car` and `Road`. If I want the `Car` to know about
`road` what other options are there than passing a reference of `Road` to `Car` in `Model` that is good in this case?

Comment: `.h` is the file name extension that indicates a header file -- you wouldn't name actual classes `Car.h` or `Road.h`.

Comment: Caleb: It´s for clarity - as class usually got a header an implementation file

Comment: There's really no need -- just use the class name.

Comment: @TomLilletveit You are actually making this harder to follow, not easier.

Comment: How is this a question about passing by reference (I don't see any code)? Do you mean "Alternatives for creating a circular reference" via header files?

Comment: Is this about passing instances or including headers? You seem possibly a little bit unclear on the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, passing pointer to a pointer is not a great design pattern to use throughout your app. It's reserved in objective-c for only select few operations, namely NSError. See bbum's response in the thread below.

[Arguments by reference in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331791/arguments-by-reference-in-objective-c)

Judging by its acceptance and it's author I'd say it's pretty good advice, though perhaps not "gospel". You could certainly pass pointers to pointers all you want, but it's probably not the best approach.

The alternative is to consider what values you're considering passing by reference (meaning pointer-to-a-pointer) and then think about the design of the methods/functions so that you might encapsulate those values into a class that is returned from your method/function.

Comment: I wouldn't consider passing by reference to mean 'pointer-to-a-pointer'; in normal usage it means passing in a pointer.  Any Obj-C class is passed by reference, although there are rare cases where you want to modify the reference, like the `NSError` one you've identified.

Comment: I think this is what the OP means, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @sapi, you're right. The semantics are little confusing but I did mean "pointer to a pointer" and not passing by reference. I understand that obj-c objects are always passed by reference. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, objects are always passed by reference, but you can mitigate that by carefully designing your classes.

For example, `NSString` and `NSNumber` are always passed by reference, but you can treat them as if they're passed by value because they're immutable. You can't alter an `NSString` (only an `NSMutableString`) or `NSNumber`, so it doesn't really matter whether you're passing by value or by reference.

Similarly, copying objects and using `-isEqual:` to compare them later can simulate pass-by-value. `NSDictionary` does this—`-setObject:forKey:` copies the key and uses only the copy, while `-objectForKey:` uses `-isEqual:` and `-hash` to compare keys.

In your case, you might be able to make `Road` objects immutable (or at least never be mutated after they're loaded) if your "map" of roads is fixed and you don't need to link roads back to cars. If you do that, then passing by reference is effectively a helpful optimization, not a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

There really are no other options. Objects are *always* accessed via pointers in Objective-C. There's no way to declare a variable that *is* an object, you can only create variables that refer to objects.

Comment: I was thinking if there where alternatives like how I design my classes like using a Singelton etc.. but singelton is not suitable in this case.